# Pagination in Laravel with JSON Object

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, client-side

Hello i have a data with xml format, and i've tried to convert it with JSON. And i would like to make a pagging in laravel. Here i give my code in controller. And i get the error with my code

Error :

> FatalErrorException in PageController.php line 189: Call to a member
>   function paginate() on string

This is my controller :

```
public function soap(Request $request){ 
            $this->validate($request, [
            'nama' => 'required',
            'negara' => 'required',
            'pencarian'=>'required'
            ]);

            $count = Pengaturan::where('key', 'visitor')        
            ->first();
            $array=array_map('intval', str_split($count->value));

            $kategori = $request->input("pencarian");
            $nama = $request->input("nama");
            $negara = $request->input("negara");
            $pages = $request->get("pageby");

            $soapClient = new SoapClient("http://interop.bnp2tki.go.id/perwakilanWS/wsdl"); 
            $param;     
            if($kategori=="2"){ //search by paspor
                $param = array( 
                'user_id'=>'kjri_jed', 
                'user_pass'=>'123',
                'paspor'=>$nama         
                );

                $error = 0; 
                try { 
                    $info = $soapClient->__call("ws_view_tkibypaspor", $param);         
                    if($info!="notfound"){                  
                        $informasi = preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $info);
                        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($informasi);
                        $data = $xml->tki_data;
                        $pagess = $xml->total_page;
                        $hasil = array($data);
                        $json = json_encode($hasil);
                        $paging = $json->paginate(10);

                        return view('page.search-tki', compact('data', 'array','paging'));
                        }else{
                        $data=$info;
                        return view('page.search-tki', compact('data', 'array'));                   
                    }
                    } catch (SoapFault $fault) { 
                    return view('page.search-tki', compact('data', 'array'));
                } 

                }else{ //by nama
                $param = array( 
                'user_id'=>'kjri_jed', 
                'user_pass'=>'123',
                'nama'=>$nama,
                'negara'=>$negara,
                'page'=>$pages          
                );
                $error = 0; 

                try { 
                    $info = $soapClient->__call("ws_view_tkibyname", $param); 
                    if($info!="notfound"){
                        $informasi = preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $info);
                        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($informasi);
                        $data = $xml->tki_data;
                        $pagess = $xml->total_page;

                        //merubah ke pagination
                        //$hasil = array($data);
                        $json = json_encode($data);
                        $paging = $json->paginate(10);

                        return view('page.search-tki', compact('data', 'array','pagess','nama','negara','kategori','json','paging'));
                        }else{
                        $data=$info;
                        return view('page.search-tki', compact('data', 'array'));                   
                    }
                    } catch (SoapFault $fault) { 
                    return view('page.search-tki', compact('data', 'array'));
                } 

            }       
        }
```

is any one can help me?
pleasee :)

Answer (score 0):

the method `paginate()` works on `QueryBuilder::class` instance.

what you can do is use the laravel `Collection`.

```
$informasi = preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $info);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($informasi);
$data = $xml->tki_data;
$pagess = $xml->total_page;
$hasil = array($data);
$page = collect($hasil)->take(10);
$paging = $page->toJson();
```

or you can use `forPage($pageNumber, $pageCount)` method

```
$informasi = preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $info);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($informasi);
$data = $xml->tki_data;
$pagess = $xml->total_page;
$hasil = array($data);
$page = collect($hasil)->forPage(1,10);
$paging = $page->toJson();
```

Comment: thank you for replying my question, i will try your response:)

Comment: i've witten the code in controller and compact it. and i've tried with method render() in view. I got error like this : "
FatalErrorException in 81b2083a324452e74994deeb75563ac98b3752fb.php line 59:
Call to a member function render() on string" . So how use it to the view?

Comment: what is the method `render()` supposed to do ? $paging is a string in a json format.

Comment: it supposed to display paging in view